# Series RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, electromagnetism, wireless

Suppose a series RLC circuit has its resonance frequency f_r. If we apply AC current of frequency f_r to this series RLC circuit then circuit has maximum current as output. My question is little bit hypothetical. What will be the output of the series RLC circuit if we apply AC current of mixed frequency where one of its frequency is f_r? For simplicity we can assume AC current made up of two frequencies, (say f_r and f_s) where f_r != f_s.

PS: I am very sorry for any incovenience. Please comment if still there is ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

> *My question is little bit hypothetical. What will be the output of the
> series RLC circuit if we apply AC \$\color{red}{\text{current}}\$ of mixed frequency where one
> of its frequency is f_r?*

$$\boxed{\text{The question is about a} \color{red}{\text{ current }} \text{source}}$$

Whatever current you apply to the input of the series RLC you will also get on the output. There is nowhere else for it to pass to. That is what current sources do - they override the presented impedance and fulfil their birth-right to maintain a constant current.

$$\boxed{\text{Maybe it's about a voltage source???}}$$

Even if you applied a voltage source at the input, you'd still get the same voltage at the output.

$$\boxed{\text{Maybe it's about something else???}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Since Series RLC circuit outputs the resonance frequeny current for the AC current with frequency f_r and for the any other current it outputs 0 current. My simple question is weatuer it follow homorphism or not. I mean for the inputs mentioned in the question, the AC current must be of frequency f_r. Feel free to ask if there is needed more explanation.

Comment: @AbhilashKurmi if you're done with this now then please consider formally accepting the answer that best suits your needs or, raise another comment if something needs clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering a concept called [frequency response](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/control_systems/control_systems_frequency_response_analysis.htm).

This is the electrical analogue to hitting a bell with a hammer.  The hammer strike injects a wide range of frequencies into the system, which filters these frequencies according to its resonance.

This is formalized with the [impulse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), which uniformly contains all frequencies; when you inject this into an RLC circuit, the output is the circuit's transfer function.